# Putting text into textbox in JavaScript from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, textbox

I'm new to JavaScript and I am having problems putting information read from a created array into a text box.I am using Dashcode, but modifying elements in the `main.js` file as I go along. I have created an array, can get the value from the array, I just can't manage to get the information into the text box.

The line which doesn't work is:

```
document.getElementById("text").setAttribute("text",textLocation);
```

where `text` is the ID of the box, and textLocation is the information I am trying to pass into the text box.

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

The rest of the code is below.

```
var n = null;
var textLocation;
var myArray = new Array("info one","info 2","info 3","info 4","info 5","info 6","info 7","info 8","info 9");

function toPreviousImage(event)
{

    var list = document.getElementById("grid").object; 
    var selectedObjects = list.selectedObjects();
    var name = selectedObjects[0].valueForKey("name");
    var textinfo = selectedObjects[0].valueForKey("info"); 

    name= name - 1;

    if(!n || n == undefined){n=name} else {n--}

    textLocation = myArray[n];

    document.getElementById("text").setAttribute("text",textLocation);
```

Comment: You may find the developer mneu, esp. Web Inspector, in Safari handy for debugging, if you haven't discovered it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe attribute you want to set is 'value', not 'text'.

```
document.getElementById("text").setAttribute("value",textLocation);
```